# PHPUnit filtering not working with setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass()

Tags: php, phpunit

We use PHPUnit filtering quite extensively and it appears that it doesn't prevent us from executing setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass() in test classes that don't match the filtered results.

For those unaware, you can use the `--filter` option to filter your PHPUnit tests.

Other testing frameworks like mocha don't execute fixtures unless they match the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to start by saying that I have great respect for all the phpunit contributors.

Our workaround was to develop a new base class that provides a new set of constructs that can be used instead of setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass().

```
class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  /**
   * PHPUnit has a serious design flaw where setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass() are still
   * executed for all test classes even if they don't match the filter. This appears to be due to
   * PHPUnit applying the filter after these fixtures. Fortunately, with a little magic, we can
   * define constructs for before() and after() that achieve our desired behavior. Some may say that
   * this is not a PHPUnit bug, but other testing frameworks like mocha don't execute any of the
   * fixtures unless the filters match.
   */

  /**
   * @var boolean True if we are executing this test
   */
  protected static $executing = false;

  /**
   * Use instead of setUpBeforeClass() to create a fixture that is called once per test class and
   * not called unless it is in the filter results.
   */
  public static function before() {}

  /**
   * Use instead of tearDownAfterClass() to create a fixture that is called once per test class and
   * not called unless it is in the filter results.
   */
  public static function after() {}

  /**
   * A base method for setUp() that uses the $executing flag to determine whether or not to run
   * before(). We cannot use setUpBeforeClass() here as setUpBeforeClass() will run before any
   * filters are applied.
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    if (!self::$executing) {
      static::$executing = true;
      static::before();
    }
  }

  /**
   * A base method for tearDownAfterClass() that uses the $executing flag to determine whether or
   * not to run after()
   */
  public static function tearDownAfterClass() {
    if (static::$executing) {

      // Set to false so that this doesn't trigger execution of another classes fixtures as $executing
      // is a static member
      static::$executing = false;

      static::after();
    }
  }
}
```

you can then use the new before() and after() constructs like so and they will not be executed if the test is not part of the filtered results:

```
class MyTest extends Test {

  public static function before() {
    // Code done once before all tests
  }

  public function testFoo() {
    // Test something
  }

  public static function after() {
    // Code done once after all tests
  }

}
```

Comment: Not the best solution ever, but glad that it worked for you. Do you happen to know whether it is a bug in PHPUnit or an undocumented feature?